# How to read buffered data as it arrives rather than when the buffer is full?

Tags: java, android, tcp, inputstream, bufferedreader

Using Android, I am reading data (a signed byte array) from a microcontroller. I understand that `BufferedReader` has a buffer size of 8192 bytes. I'm sending about 200-300 bytes every second, this means at the moment I have to wait about 25-30 seconds (8192/300) before the debugger will read the byte array.

I want to be reading this every time the Android receives the 200-300 byte array (every full TCP packet) is there a way to alter the maximum byte size of the `BufferedReader`, or is there an alternative way of doing this?

```
private BufferedReader input;
  input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
      this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
  ...
  ...
  while(true)
  {
    try
    {
      Log.i("WaitingForSomeData","");
      String read = input.readLine();
      byte[] bytes = read.getBytes();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am reading data (a signed byte array) from a microcontroller

You should be using a [`BufferedInputStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) if you want to buffer binary data.

You are currently attempting to read a character stream. Your `readLine()` method will block until either `\r`, `\n` or `\r\n` is received. I'm guessing this causes your delay, since you are waiting for an `0x0A` or `0x0D` byte to conveniently arrive.

Comment: I'll try that! :) that does make sense, thanks a lot!